# Issue with searchbox on bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Issue with searchbox on bootstrap navbar - I got an issue on bootstrap navbar. searchbox on navbar comes out and placed underneath (on tab/mobiledeviceview).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekraj_kr/c9ryqrc7/1/)

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">   
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WOMEN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KIDS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GOODSALE</a></li>
              </ul>
              </div>
            </div>                
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right " role="search">  
                <div class="form-group form_search">
                    <input type="text" class=" search_box" placeholder="SEARCH" />
                </div>
            </form>               
        </div>
    </div>                      
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Its because the search bar is outside the `navbar-collapse` div, try putting the search form inside this div.

Answer (score 2):

The row needs to be inside navbar-header like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">WOMEN</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">KIDS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">GOODSALE</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
               <form class="navbar-form navbar-right " role="search">
                  <div class="form-group form_search">
                     <input type="text" class=" search_box" placeholder="SEARCH" />
                  </div>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Good spot. Here is a fix. You will need to add CSS to target mobile/tablet and revert the HTML changes we made before.

http://jsfiddle.net/londonfed/c9ryqrc7/10/

Comment: Thts gud. it worked even without mediaquery but got a new issue on padding with that nav links  http://jsfiddle.net/vivekraj_kr/c9ryqrc7/11/